# mysql select multiple tables and bring back all results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select everything from multiple tables where there are 2 conditions.

But they only bring back a single result from the second table, instead of everything

Here is the MySql code

```
SELECT *
  FROM `core_users`.`users`
     LEFT JOIN `core`.`orders`
       ON `core_users`.`users`.`uid` = `core`.`orders`.`uid`
     LEFT JOIN `core_users`.`crm`
       ON `core_users`.`users`.`uid` = `core_users`.`crm`.`uid`
  WHERE (`core_users`.`users`.`signup_timestamp` BETWEEN '1476626400' AND '1476712800'
     OR (`core_users`.`crm`.`type` = 'refresh_5in5' AND `core_users`.`crm`.`value` BETWEEN '1476626400' AND '1476712800') )
```

This just brings back 1 result from the crm table. However I want it to bring back all the results from the crm table.

How do I bring back **everything** from `users`, `orders`, and `crm` while having a WHERE clause on both tables?

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Are you sure that the results that fit to that WHERE are more than one ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `select users.*, orders.*, crm.*`

Please note that, in such case if you have common columns in any of these table like `id` in every table it would cause an **ambiguous column** name error. To get rid of that you need to specify these with alias name `users.id as user_id`, `orders.id as order_id`, `crm.id as crm_id` and so on.

Comment: This still only brings back 1 row for each user. Not everything from all tables. I think its the WHERE clause that makes it happen.

Comment: Then adding some sample data and expected output in your question can help you to get quick answer.